# Cannot record alphanumeric characters with pynput python

Tags: python, listener, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric, pynput

How to keep track of *alphanumeric characters* and *non special characters* (space bar, delete, tab, etc) in **pynput**. I am using the below code. This code outputs only the *special characters* and not any other characters input through keyboard.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

#defining function to print when key is pressed
def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

#defining function to print when key is released
def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: its working in my pc

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. You say "this code outputs only the special characters and not any other characters input through keyboard". But if I try it, it reports *all* keypresses and releases, for example `'t' pressed`. I tried it in IDLE and in PyCharm and can't reproduce the behaviour you report.

Comment: @BoarGules I am not getting the above mentioned output... Is it because of the editor I am using?

Comment: Might be. What are you using? Have you tried running this code in `python.exe`?

Comment: Sublime.. I'll try and report back

Comment: @BoarGules No change in output even when running in `python.exe`. When I press any alphanumeric character it just doesn't respond. Are you just typing the character or giving utf16 encoding?

Comment: I'm just typing the character, working with exactly the code that you posted, except that I had to fix up the indentation errors. It looks like you're not running the code you think you are running.

Comment: I ran the same code on widows PC and its running fine.

Comment: Having the same issue on MasOS.